# match content with preg_match_all

Tags: php

I want to get the **titles** text from the following `$content` into an array. So I'm trying to use `preg_match_all`, however I'm making some mistake in the expression, because it does not select the title correctly.

```
$content = '[sc-item title="Item1 Title"] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum scelerisque posuere euismod. P [/sc-item][sc-item title="Item2 Title"] Lorem [/sc-item]';

$titles = array();
preg_match_all( '/sc-item title=\"([^\']+)\"/i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );

if( isset($matches[1]) ){ 
    //$titles = $matches[1]; 
    var_dump($matches[1]);  
}
```

In the above example, I want to get the text **Item1 Title** and **Item2 Title**.

Comment: What are you getting now?

Comment: You can just echo `$matches[1]` instead of `vardump`, as `$metches[1]` is a string.

Comment: It selects part of the content too. I tried Kazeko's answer and that seems to work. Thanks for your answer also, I haven't tried that yet. Do you know what would be the problem with above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pattern

```
preg_match_all( '/sc-item title="(.*?)"/i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

? means non-greedy; or use modifier

```
preg_match_all( '/sc-item title="([^\']+)"/iU', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

It has the same result.

By the way, I think double quote escape is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, it works, do you know what was the problem with my expression ?

Comment: Since regular expression is "greedy" by default - it will match as many as it can. Therefore in your pattern, it matches until the last double quote (i.e. the double quote after "Item2 Title").

To make the matching non-greedy, use "?" or modifier "U"
[http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `g` flag:

```
preg_match_all( '/sc-item title=\"([^\']+)\"/ig', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```